# Best way to clear redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have question about clearing redux state.
I have state named `search` for searching address with fetching. It's structure like this

```
search:{
  status: 'INIT',
  results: [],
}
```

`status` is a flag for async request something like 'SUCCESS' or 'FAILURE'.

`results` is a result of fetching.

When user search address with some search word, results has result of fetching.
And My component render like this,

```
<div>
   {this.props.results.map((result,i)=>{
     <div>{result}</div>
   )}
</div>
```

So my problem is when user try to search again after some other works, component render previous search result because `results` is not clear.

Currently, I dispatch action 'CLEAR_SEARCH' that initialize `search` state, after works using results has done. But i think it's not a good way.

Is there any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start initialising the new request, you can dispatch an action call START_LOADING

```
 dispatch(startLoadingAction())
 try {
     const result = await fetch...
     dispatch(successAction(result));
 } catch {
     dispatch(failureAction());
 }
```

then handle it like this:

```
 case START_LOADING:
     state = {
         status: 'LOADING',
         result: [],
     };
     break;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a common pattern to have requests in redux look more like 
`{
  isLoading: false,
  data: [],
  error: false,
  isLoaded: true,
  hasFailed: false,
}` so that when you clear or re-issue the search result the status of the request changes, and you can display based on the request instead of just the presence of data.